# smtp - Как обойти гугл?

Tags: email, ip, gmail, smtp-server

Возможно и на американском Stackoverflow уже есть ответ но я спрошу (если что подправьте):

Как возможно обойти блокировку гугла?

Использую `hmailserver` в качестве почтового сервера и каждый раз когда отправляю сообщение на гугл почту приходит вот это:

```
our message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

    Sent: Sun, 28 May 2017 12:43:03 +0300
    Subject: test

The following recipient(s) could not be reached:

mykola.kikets@gmail.com
Error Type: SMTP
Remote server (64.233.161.26) issued an error.
hMailServer sent: .
Remote server replied: 550-5.7.1 [46.164.138.78] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to
550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your
550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at
550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError 87si3976206lft.315 - gsmtp



hMailServer
```

как все таки обойти блокировку?

Правка: если необходимо: использую домен от [freenom.com](http://freenom.com)

Comment: Гугл вас не видит. .

Comment: а как сделать так чтоб видел...

Comment: https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25826

Comment: Это не похоже на Gmail IP-адрес. Вы пытаетесь перенаправить на gmail через другой сервер? Или это, возможно, ваш публичный IP-адрес, и вы пытаетесь соединиться с самим собой?

Comment: `64.233.161.26` - не мой адрес... ,а `46.164.138.78` - мой

Answer (score 0):

Нужно установить DKIM на сервере где smtp. Иначе твоя почта не будет проходить проверку в google и сразу отбрасываться.

Comment: есть какой то титориал по инсталяции DKIM? чтото не получается его поставить...